# What does this KeyError mean? in Accumulation key value of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.8

(1) : This does work, but it doesn't accumulate.

```
word_dict = {'now': 3, 'this': 3, 'now': 2, 'this': 2}
new_word_dict = {}

for word in word_dict:
    n = word_dict.get(word)

    new_word_dict[word] = n
    print(new_word_dict)
```

(1) the result

```
    {'now': 2}
    {'now': 2, 'this': 2}
```

(2) : This doesn't work. What the KeyError is ?

```
word_dict = {'now': 3, 'this': 3, 'now': 2, 'this': 2}
new_word_dict = {}

for word in word_dict:
    n = word_dict.get(word)

    new_word_dict[word] += n
    print(new_word_dict)
```

(2) the result

```
  ---->  new_word_dict[word] += n
  
 KeyError: 'now'
```

Comment: With `+=` you're trying to add a value *to* something. That something must exist beforehand. If it doesn't, you get an error.

Comment: A dictionary can't contain the same key twice anyway, your `word_dict` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: It is equivalent to `new_word_dict[word] = new_word_dict[word] + n`, and the right hand side is complaining about the missing key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyError is because the key you're trying to increment doesn't exist, but I think there's more than just this issue in your example.

Assuming that the result you want is `new_word_dict` to be an accumulation of `word_dict` you first need to change the type of `word_dict` to a list of tuples (because, as @deceze pointed out in a comment, duplicate keys aren't allowed in dicts). So I think you want to end up with something like this:

```py
words == [("now", 3), ("this", 3), ("now", 2), ("this", 2)]
words_accumulated == {"now": 5, "this": 5}
```

then your loop could be changed to

```py
words = [("now", 3), ("this", 3), ("now", 2), ("this", 2)]
words_accumulated = {}
for word, val in words: # unpack each tuple into two variables
  existing_val = words_accumulated.setdefault(word, 0) # if it doesn't exist yet, set to 0. This solves your KeyError
  words_accumulated[word] = existing_val + val
```

For further research on how to do this better, look up [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) and maybe some of the tools in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Answer (score 0):

`new_word_dict[word] += n`
need the latest value of new_word_dict[word] if it's not initialize it should crash.

to fix this, you can check if new_word_dict exist like
`new_word_dict[word] = n if new_word_dict[word] else new_word_dict[word] + n`

You can use too word_dict.items() like `for key, value in word_dict.items()`